# Android plain text notes app supporting Markdown

Tags: android, note-taking, markdown

I'm looking for a lightweight plain text notes taking app that supports Markdown and that simply saves each note as a .txt file for Android.

I have been using [Denkzettel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.silli.notizen) but I didn't like it.

The app should save automatically as I edit the file and should not add any extra character to the text when it is saved.

I don't care about seeing the formatted text on the phone, so a simple text editor would be good.

Comment: Never used any of them (yet) – but my list of [Markdown Editors](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office#group_107) should get you started while you're waiting for good recommendations :)

Comment: Awesome list. I'll check them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody put as an answer some apps but the post was deleted afterwards. I was able to try out the apps suggested and I found `writely` to be the best one. It is available on `fdroid`.